# GDAL reprojection 4326 to 3857 creates gap

Tags: coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp, mapnik

I have an EPSG:4326 tif covering the world that I need to reproject to EPSG:3857 in order to use it with Mapnik to create a map.

When displaying the original tif and leaving Mapnik doing the reprojection, it is working perfectly. But when using GDAL to reproject beforehand, I get a small gap at the right edge of the tif. On the following screenshot of the tif displayed in a mapping app (like Google Maps), you can see it at the middle of the picture:

[image: gap]

Here are the commands I used to create the displayed picture:

```
gdalwarp \
    -co COMPRESS=LZW -co PREDICTOR=2 \
    -multi \
    -t_srs "EPSG:3857" \
    -r cubicspline \
    -tap \
    -tr 10000 10000 \
    world-4326.tif \
    world-3857-10000.tif

gdaldem color-relief \
    -co COMPRESS=LZW -co PREDICTOR=2 \
    world-3857-10000.tif \
    relief-colors.txt \
    relief-world-3857-10000.tif
```

Is there a way to remove that gap with GDAL?

Comment: When I look at the right edge of the picture I don't see a gap.  Maybe you could draw a circle around the gap to highlight it,  and also include a zoomed-in picture?

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't clear enough. The gap is at the right of my tif, and at the middle of the screenshot (the white line). The tif is being displayed in a mapping app (like Google Maps) on the screenshot.

Comment: maybe your problem is connected with nodata values on the borders of the tiff image - I also had this problem when projecting tiffs to Web Merkator. I used dstNodata=0 parameter in gdalwarp. (if not work, try this https://www.gdal.org/nearblack.html or srcNodata=0 parameter)

Comment: @Jane I don't think so: in my relief-color.txt file, the nodata is set to red, but the gap is of the colour of my background.

Comment: gdaldem you execute after gdalwarp, aren't you? I believe this white gap appears at gdalwarp step. - I recommend you to take a closer look at the raster border before gdaldem

Comment: Yes of course I execute gdaldem after gdalwarp. And yes the gap is produced by gdalwarp, gdaldem is "only" coloring the tif. Seems I managed to reproject the file with QGIS on my home computer, I'm uploading it to my server to test it with Mapnik. Still, the GDAL problem remains.

Comment: A quick precision: the gap is much wider > 85°N and < 85°S with GDAL. It doesn't really matter as I won't be showing those latitudes on my map (EPSG:3857 isn't supposed to support them), but maybe that the fact that my original 4326 tif is covering those latitudes is the source of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that the problem came from the fact that EPSG:3857 is only covering 85.06° north and south, and not 90° (like EPSG:4326, the projection of my original tif). When adding an extent to gdalwarp, it is working. Working command:

```
gdalwarp \
-co COMPRESS=LZW -co PREDICTOR=2 \
-multi \
-t_srs "EPSG:3857" \
-te_srs "EPSG:4326" \
-te -180 -85.06 180 85.06 \
-r cubic \
~/data/gebco/raw/raw.tif \
raw-3857.tif
```

EDIT: I had the problem again on another worldwide dataset. Using -te didn't work, -tap neither. I was using GDAL 2.x.x and upgraded to the latest (3.1.2) finally fixed the problem!